# List Lua functions in a file

Tags: function, lua

How can I list all the functions included in a Lua source file?

For example, I have fn.lua which contains

```
function test1()
        print("Test 1")
end

function test2()
        print("Test 2")
end
```

And I wish to be able to display those function names (test1, test2) from another Lua script.

The only way I can figure at the moment is to include the file using require, then list the functions in _G - but that will include all the standard Lua functions as well.

Of course I could just parse the file manually using the string search functions, but that doesn't seem very Lua to me!

This will eventually form part of a process that allows the developer to write functions in Lua, and the operator to select which of those functions are called from a list in Excel (yuk!).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you put them all in a "module" (which you should probably do, anyway):

```
mymodule = { }
function mymodule.test1()
    print("Test 1")
end

function module.test2()
    print("Test 2")
end

return mymodule
```

It becomes trivial:

```
mymodule = require"mymodule"

for fname,obj in pairs(mymodule) do
    if type(obj) == "function" then
        print(fname)
    end
end
```

If you absolutely have to keep them in raw form, you'd have to load them in a different way to separate your global environment, and then iterate over it in a similar way (over the inner env's cleaned `_G`, perhaps).

Comment: I had to change the format of the input file:  'mymodule = {}
    function mymodule.test1()
            print("Test 1")
    end

    function mymodule.test2()
            print("Test 2")
    end

return mymodule'

Comment: Also - (and I don't understand why), the function names in mymodule table are strings not functions. But mymodule.test1() works fine.

Comment: @RichardHarvie aah, another silly mistake. Of course the key will be the name, thus string!

Answer (score 3):

I see three ways:

1. Save the names in `_G` before loading your script and compare to the names left in `_G` after loading it. I've seen some code for this, either in the Lua mailing list or in the wiki, but I can't find a link right now.
2. Report the globals used in a function by parsing `luac` listings, as in http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2012-12/msg00397.html.
3. Use my bytecode inspector [lbci](http://www.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/~lhf/ftp/lua/#lbci) from within Lua, which contains an example that reports globals.

Comment: The idea with a difference of `_G` before and `_G` after is really nice, I wouldn't think about it.

Comment: I thought about comparing _G, but hoped there was a simpler way. I like the idea of using luac since I was thinking of using luac for basic syntax checking.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this, it's better to define the function is a package, [as described in Programming in Lua book](http://www.lua.org/pil/15.1.html):

```
functions = {}
function functions.test1() print('foo') end
function functions.test2() print('bar') end
return functions
```

Then you can simply iterate your table `functions`.